# UIImagePickerController does not forward pinch/zoom events (multi touch) to the CameraOverlayView

Tags: ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I have developed an application on the appstore that uses an overlay over the camera (UIImagePickerController) which the user can pan and zoom using touch gestures. The overlay view is a subclass to a UIView and overrides the touches events from UIResponder to modify the overlay view accordingly.

This works fine in iOS3-4 but zoom stopped working for iOS5. It seems as the UIImagePickerController does only forward single touch events and takes over the pinching gestures to enable zoom of the camera.

Do anyone know how to handle this? I would like to disable the zoom of the camera and enable it on my overlay view again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the Overlay view on top of window instead of using cameraoverlayview.

Comment: Could you provide some code? My view still doesn't receive touch events.

Comment: Are you adding the overlayview on the window?. Something like [self.view.window addSubview:myOverlayView];